# Setting up Smarty directories and paths

Tags: filesystems, smarty

Just a general question for those of you working with the Smarty templating engine.

How are you setting up your file structure? I'd like to follow an MVC format, but I'm not sure how to include all the CSS, Javascript, etc. with the Smarty controller and templates without including these ridiculous paths.

Has anyone worked with this? Anyone have any insight?

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mmmmmm

I would recommend another structure.

suppouse this:

document  root: my_app/public_html/

```
my_app/
   - lib
   - app
   - public_html/
     - css/
     - js/
     - images/
   - cache/
   - compiled_templates/
   - templates/
     - mails/
        - html/
        - text/
     - frontend/
     - backend/
     - xml/
```

in this was your templates are outside the document root, so.. are protected. In the other way.. anyway can go to my/site/templates/somefile.tpl

your _public_html_ folder should contain all files that users can access.

the *lib* folder contains the all utility classes you may use: smarty, database, etc..

the *app* folder contains all the bussines files, etc..etc.

anyway I think the most important point is to have the frontend and the backend in different levels.

saludos

Answer (score 0):

```
/
/includes/smarty
/includes/class.foobar.php
/includes/class.foobar2.php
/templates/myTemplate.tpl
/templates_c/

/js/
/js/jquery/jquery.js

/css/
/css/style.css
...
```

works nicely

including a file, which loads all stuff:

```
require_once 'includes/class.foobar.php';
require_once 'smarty/Smarty.class.php';
```